# javascript - loading data from two xml files into one array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

file1.xml:

```
<CustomersRoot>
    <Customer>
        <CustomerID>1</CustomerID>
    <CustomerName>Lucy</CustomerName>
</Customer>
...
```

file2.xml:

```
<OrdersRoot>
<Order>
    <OrderID>1</OrderID>
    <CustomerID>1</CustomerID> <!--foreign key-->
    <OrderDescription>Order #1</OrderDescription>
</Order>
<Order>
    <OrderID>2</OrderID>
    <CustomerID>1</CustomerID> <!--foreign key-->
    <OrderDescription>Order #2</OrderDescription>
</Order>
...
```

Currently, I am loading each file into separate arrays using ajax, and displaying each array on an html page. However, I want to combine the data based on the one-to-many relationship. Essentially, I want to display the data like this:

Lucy
    Order #1
    Order #2
...
What is the most simple way to achieve this?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: "Currently, I am loading each file into separate arrays using ajax, and displaying each array on an html page." - Show us this code!!

Answer (score 0):

Please check it.

As per your question i have made this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var orderSummery = new Array();
  var orderXml ='<OrdersRoot> <Order> <OrderID>1</OrderID> <CustomerID>1</CustomerID> <!--foreign key--> <OrderDescription>Order #1</OrderDescription> </Order> <Order> <OrderID>2</OrderID> <CustomerID>1</CustomerID> <!--foreign key--> <OrderDescription>Order #2</OrderDescription> </Order> </OrdersRoot>';
 var customerXml='<CustomersRoot> <Customer> <CustomerID>1</CustomerID> <CustomerName>Lucy</CustomerName> </Customer> </CustomersRoot>';
 var customerObj = $.parseXML(customerXml);
 $cust= $(customerObj);
 $cust.find('CustomersRoot').find('Customer').each(function(i) {
        var custid= $(this).find('CustomerID').text();
    var custname = $(this).find('CustomerName').text();
    var orderProduct='';
    var orderObj = $.parseXML(orderXml);
    $odr= $(orderObj);
    $odr.find('OrdersRoot').find('Order').each(function(j) {
                var custrefid= $(this).find('CustomerID').text();
          if(custid === custrefid){
                orderProduct+=$(this).find('OrderDescription').text() + " ";
          }
    });
    if(orderProduct !== '')
    orderSummery.push({
                    name: custname,
                  orderProduct : orderProduct
              });
 });

 console.log(orderSummery);
});
```

let me know it is working or not...